# How to remove unmounted drive folders from root directory

Tags: finder, mount, sudo, ntfs

[image: All deleted drives]

Recently I have noticed that in the `/` directory, there were a lot mounted volumes from my old NTFS drive (which I haven't been using for a long time). Several failed attempts to delete them are listed here:

- `sudo rm -rf My\ Passport*` in bash, it just shows it is a read-only file, `chmod` tells me I do not have privilege to do this.
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and try to change the permissions to read-write, Finder just tells me that as the system admin I have no access to these folders.

I tried one last straw to update my system to Catalina (which I was reluctant due to Spotlight problematic indexing problem reported by users), and these things are still here.

Comment: I dont have a direct answer. You can always try reinstalling Mojave or giving Apple Support a call based on your region. Make sure you speak to a Mac senior advisor and see if they have any recommendations. I would definitely recommend backing up your Mac at this point, just to be safe